# Bulk API fails to insert w/ null RecordTypeId, but Rest API succeeds

Tags: record-type, bulk-api, insert

I've come across an error where the Bulk API and the Rest API differ in their behavior when inserting records with record types. To sum up the problem:

> Suppose one or more custom record types are defined on an object, and the user has permission to use all custom record types, in addition to the `Master` record type. Why does the Rest API allow insertion of records with the `Master` record type, but the Bulk API returns an error for them?

Is this a bug in the API, or is it behaving as designed? There does not appear to be any documentation or open questions regarding this behavior.

## Example

To illustrate the point, I've defined two record types on the Account object—`Customer` and `Partner`.

### Profile and Permission Set Setup

The user performing the insertion has the following permissions:

1. `--Master--` is selected for the record type on the user profile; and
2. Both `Customer` and `Partner` record types are assigned via a permission set.

This is confirmed in [How is record type access specified?](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=permissions_record_type_access.htm), this enables the creation of records (Accounts) with one of three Record Types: `Customer`, `Partner`, and `Master`.

---

[image: user profile]

[image: user permission set]

---

### Rest API Insertion

The REST API happily inserts three Accounts with all possible record types:

```bash
SESSION_ID='MY-SESSION-ID'
INSTANCE_URL=https://MY-INSTANCE.salesforce.com

# Create account with `Master` record type.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/ -d '{ "Name": "REST API account, record type = Master" }'

# Create account with `Partner` record type.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/ -d '{ "Name": "REST API account, record type = Partner", "RecordTypeId": "0126g000000kq3rAAA" }'

# Create account with `Customer` record type.
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/ -d '{ "Name": "REST API account, record type = Customer", "RecordTypeId": "0126g000000kq3wAAA" }'
```

### Bulk API

Performing the same insertion with the Bulk API however, yields a different result:

```bash
# Create a job.
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' $INSTANCE_URL/services/async/48.0/job --data-binary @- <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
    <operation>insert</operation>
    <object>Account</object>
    <contentType>CSV</contentType>
</jobInfo>
EOF

# Add a batch to the job.
# NOTE: Substitute the job id returned in previous command.
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' $INSTANCE_URL/services/async/48.0/job/7506g000004Jih3AAC/batch --data-binary @- <<EOF
Name,RecordTypeId
"Bulk API account, record type = Master",#N/A
"Bulk API account, record type = Partner",0126g000000kq3rAAA
"Bulk API account, record type = Customer",0126g000000kq3wAAA
EOF

# Close the job.
# NOTE: Substitute the job id.
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/xml' $INSTANCE_URL/services/async/48.0/job/7506g000004Jih3AAC --data-binary @- <<EOF
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jobInfo xmlns="http://www.force.com/2009/06/asyncapi/dataload">
  <state>Closed</state>
</jobInfo>
EOF

# Get batch results.
# NOTE: Substitute the job id _and_ the batch id returned in second command.
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: $SESSION_ID" $INSTANCE_URL/services/async/48.0/job/7506g000004JigZAAS/batch/7516g0000046ci9AAA/result
```

The error returned indicates that the one account which failed to insert is the one with the master record type:

```csv
"Id","Success","Created","Error"
"","false","false","INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY:Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: :RecordTypeId --"
"0016g00000Db9ykAAB","true","true",""
"0016g00000Db9ylAAB","true","true",""
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution found!

Apparently the problem was in one small tweak to the batch CSV. Notice the use of a blank string rather than `#N/A` for the first row's `RecordTypeId`:

```bash
curl -H "X-SFDC-Session: $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: text/csv' $INSTANCE_URL/services/async/48.0/job/7506g000004Jih3AAC/batch --data-binary @- <<EOF
Name,RecordTypeId
"Bulk API account, record type = Master",
"Bulk API account, record type = Partner",0126g000000kq3rAAA
"Bulk API account, record type = Customer",0126g000000kq3wAAA
EOF
```

It seems that the Bulk API rejects records with `RecordTypeId` explicitly set to `#N/A` in the presence of custom record types available to the user. While the rationale behind this is not clear, it is at least consistent with the Rest API's behavior if the `RecordTypeId` is *explicitly* set to null,

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer $SESSION_ID" -H 'Content-Type: application/json' $INSTANCE_URL/services/data/v48.0/sobjects/Account/ -d '{ "Name": "REST API account, record type = Partner", "RecordTypeId": null }'

# Returns:
#
# [{"message":"Record Type ID: this ID value isn't valid for the user: ","errorCode":"INVALID_CROSS_REFERENCE_KEY","fields":["RecordTypeId"]}]
```